# Delete rows in two table based on conditions in two different tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Long time viewer, first time questioner

I'm currently working on something where I have to delete data on two tables based on conditions on two different tables. I'm just a beginner in SQL and this had been at me all morning.

The two conditions are that GDPR has been set to N in the Clients table and that the Payment date in the Payment Transaction Table is greater than 30 Days

```
create proc MemberDelete

delete from ClientsPersonalInfo
from Clients, PaymentTransaction
where ClientsPersonalInfo.ClientID = Clients.ClientID and Clients.GDPR = 'N' and (select datediff(dd,PaymentDate,GETDATE()) from PaymentTransaction)>30

delete from GymCard
from Clients, PaymentTransaction
where GymCard.ClientID = Clients.ClientID and Clients.GDPR = 'N' and (select datediff(dd,PaymentDate,GETDATE()) from PaymentTransaction)>30

If @@rowcount <>1
rollback

else 
Commit
```

Really not sure where I'm going wrong with this one? The error I'm getting is the following "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

The point of the Proc is to hard delete the data from the ClientPersonalInfo and GymCard if their ClientID falls under the two conditions in the Clients and PaymentTransaction Table. This is due to the customer not ticking the box for GDPR for us to retain the information and that their last payment date is over 30 days.

Comment: *"Really not sure where I'm going wrong with this one?"* What is wrong with what you have then? You don't tell us. Also, it's *long* past time you stopped using that ancient JOIN syntax. The ANSI-92 JOIN syntax has been around for almost 30 years now.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Also helpful would be a description of what you want to do.

Comment: Apologies I should have went into more detail. I'm getting the following errors when trying to exec it. "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.". What I want to do is if the ClientID falls under both conditions in the PaymentTransaction and Clients tables, I want to delete any data they have on the ClientsPersonalInfo and GymCard tables.

Comment: what is the relationship between Clients and PaymentTransaction?  Is that also ClientID?

Comment: Do NOT attempt to commit a transaction that your procedure did not begin. The process that starts a transaction should have (and likely assumes it has) that responsibility and relies on that to complete a (presumably) more complicated process of which your procedure is a part. If that isn't your design, then fix it.

Comment: And how much do you REALLY gain by using `datediff(dd` vs `datediff(day`? Which one is far more readable and less prone to error / misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

You must JOIN PaymentTransaction using ClientID.

You also need to JOIN GymCard with PaymentTransaction.

```
create proc MemberDelete

delete from ClientsPersonalInfo
from Clients, PaymentTransaction
where 
  ClientsPersonalInfo.ClientID = PaymentTransaction.ClientID and
  ClientsPersonalInfo.ClientID = Clients.ClientID and
  Clients.GDPR = 'N' and (select datediff(dd,PaymentDate,GETDATE())
                          from PaymentTransaction
                          where
                            ClientsPersonalInfo.ClientID = PaymentTransaction.ClientID)>30

delete from GymCard
from Clients, PaymentTransaction
where 
  GymCard.ClientID = Clients.ClientID and
  GymCard.ClientID = PaymentTransaction.ClientID and
  Clients.GDPR = 'N' and (select datediff(dd,PaymentDate,GETDATE())
                          from PaymentTransaction
                          where
                            GymCard.ClientID = PaymentTransaction.ClientID)>30

If @@rowcount <>1
rollback

else 
Commit
```

Comment: This answer is definitely on the right track, but I want to point out a couple of things. I do not think you can Rollback or Commit a transaction without a "Begin Tran". Also, the @@rowcount variable is only going to give you the row count related only to the most recent statement.